# Complex polynomial in closed unit disk with its mod value not exceeding $1$ is only of the form $z^n$

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose I'm given a polynomial $P(z)=z^n + a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+\ldots+a_0$ in closed unit disk and know that $|P(z)|$ doesn't exceed $1$ in the domain: then

$P(z) = z^n$ is it's only possible form

My work.
If $P(z)=z^n+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+\ldots+a_0$ then
$$P(1)=1+a_{n-1}+\ldots+a_0$$
and since $|P(1)| \le 1$ we have $|1+a_{n-1}+\ldots+a-0|$$\le 1$.

I'm just stuck here not able to proceed any further
Any idea as how to proceed.

Comment: You need to require that modulus 1 be achieved on the closed disc, otherwise any fixed polynomial multiplied by a small enough positive real would work. Not sure what else might be required...

Comment: @WillJagy Did you miss that the coefficient of $z^n$ is given as $1$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael I did miss it, good catch

Answer (score 2):

Define $a_n = 1$, and $a_k= 0$ for $k \notin [0,1,\ldots,n]$.  The $a_k$ are the Fourier coefficients of $P(e^{i\theta})$ as a function on $[0,2\pi]$.
[Parseval's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series#Parseval%27s_theorem) says
$$\sum_{k=0}^n |a_k|^2 = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} |P(e^{i\theta})|^2 \; d\theta $$
Since $a_n = 1$, the left side $\ge 1$.  But since $|P(e^{i\theta})|\le 1$, the right side $\le 1$.  Therefore both sides are $1$, and so $|a_k|^2 = 0$ for $0 \le k \le n-1$.